# Avoid soft keyboard from pushing my layout in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile, android-softkeyboard

I have a textbox on a screen. When textbox is focused, the layout is shrinked and all messed up. I know how to resolve this in Android SDK, by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to activity tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`. But How can I do that in Titanium? Is there a way to modify `AndroidManifest.xml` in Titanium?

Or Any other way to avoid soft keyboard from shrinking my layout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I believe you put your controls into a view. If yes, try to set the height of the view. If no, try set this at the time of window creation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128861/android-soft-keyboard-pushing-controls-up)

```
 windowSoftInputMode : Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
```

Comment: How does this work for mobile web, though? It doesn't recognize the Ti.UI.Android namespace and gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

In your main window, try this.

```
**xml**
<Alloy>
    <Window id="baseWindow" exitOnClose="true">
        <View id="learnTab" class="fullScreen" ></View>
        <View id="practiceTab" class="fullScreen"></View>
        <View id="calculateTab" class="fullScreen"></View>
        <View id="home" class="fullScreen"></View>
    </Window>
</Alloy>


**tss**
"#baseWindow": {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    navBarHidden: true,
    orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
}

"#baseWindow[platform=android]": {
    windowSoftInputMode: Ti.UI.Android.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN
}
```

I believe this helps you.